# How to calculate averages from two different tables on MySQL?

Tags: mysql

I have two different tables on MySQL which are named as "patient" and "donor". I would like to calculate averages of patients' ages and donors' ages.

I am running this query on MySQL:

```
SELECT AVG(patient_age) AS patient_age_avg FROM patient JOIN (SELECT 
AVG(donor_age) AS donor_age_avg FROM donor);
```

And it returns me this error:

> Error Code: 1248. Every derived table must have its own alias

Where am I making mistakes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use two subqueries in the `SELECT`:

```
SELECT (SELECT AVG(patient_age) FROM patient) as patient_age_avg,
       (SELECT AVG(donor_age) FROM donor) as donor_age_avg;
```

Or, if you really like, put them in the `FROM` clause and use `CROSS JOIN`:

```
SELECT p.patient_age_avg, d.donor_age_avg
FROM (SELECT AVG(patient_age) as patient_age_avg FROM patient
     ) p CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT AVG(donor_age) as donor_age_avg FROM donor
     ) d;
```

I slightly prefer the first method, because I don't have to invent table aliases -- but that is really a minor, minor, minor consideration.

Comment: Thank you so much! I have just applied the first query and it works! Thank you.